# WCF Unity and Object Disposal

Tags: .net, wcf, inversion-of-control, unity-container

If using Unity with WCF using an implementation such as that shown in this article: [WCF and Unity 2.0](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gadib/archive/2010/11/30/wcf-and-unity-2-0.aspx) are there any explicit disposal activities you need to be concerned about?

For example, let's assume an operation on the service is using an unmanaged resource as a construction injection parameter, how would this get disposed of properly? Also, I assume there is no concerns with managed resources that are being instantiated via Unity and they will be released when the service is finished with? i.e. after each call in per call.

Thanks

Comment: Unity's decommissioning support is somewhat flawed, but *can* be made to work. However, it takes up six full pages of my book to explain how to do this, so is too complex to explain here. Link, FWIW: http://affiliate.manning.com/idevaffiliate.php?id=1150_236

Comment: Can you not summarise? Thanks

Comment: @Jon Archway: You forgot the smiley :P I'm confident, being 160 pages into the book (which is fantastic) that Mark's about as good a judge of whether it can be summarised as there can possibly be. And have a good look at his posting record - there's no "it's easy but I'm not telling you how, I'll let you guess" drive by commenting to look cool in there. Aside from me being a smartarse, I can't recommend the book highly enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on selected lifetime management of your injections. I wrote [the article](http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2011/03/unity-build-in-lifetime-managers/) about different lifetime managers in Unity. In short - only `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager` (singleton) and `HiearchicalLifetimeManager` will handle dispose for you. In all other cases you are responsible for handling disposal of injections.

Comment: Thanks. Is there anything I need to be aware of in addition to this when dealing with WCF in particular?

Comment: check this article http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/introducing-unity.wcf-providing-easy-ioc-integration-for-your-wcf-services out.. it also provides complete source code and NuGet package